# Is there any feature like TDE for column level encryption on SQL Server 2008 that works transparently?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption, tde

I want to know that, is there any feature in SQL Server 2008 for column level data encryption like TDE?

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing a view with triggers for insert, update, and delete on top of your data that uses one of the cell-level encryption functions.  The user of the view would need to have the key open, but it should work aside from that.